# Send a Toast Notification from windows universal Application

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to find a way to send a toast notification from a windows universal application. The Azure documentation does mention a way to do this from a Console Application. This does not meet my use case though, where I want to send toast notifications from a windows universal application. The problem is the nugget package `Microsoft.Azure.Service.Bus` is not compatible with a windows store or `windows phone 8.1 application`.

Is there any Windows Azure library that will allow me to send a `toast notification` from Windows universal application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you wouldn't send the toast from the Universal app. You would send the toast to the app to let the user know that something occurred on the server.

If you want to schedule a toast from the app to the local system then you don't need Azure (or another web service). You can schedule that directly with a scheduled notification. See [Quickstart: Sending a toast notification (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868254(v=win.10).aspx) and [How to schedule a toast notification (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868224.aspx)

If you want to push a notification elsewhere then you can set up an Azure Notification Hub and connect to it through its [REST service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223264.aspx) via the HttpClient class.

More typically though your app would contact your back-end server to connect to the notification hub. This can be readily set up with an Azure Mobile Service. See [Add push notifications to your Mobile Services app](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-push/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wanted to confirm there was not an API form MSFT that I missed. It seems there isn't one...  From your answer, I need to either create a REST client, or create a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow two basics samples:

> Sample 1 text only

```
const ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText01;
var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

var toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Hello World!"));

var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

> Sample 2 text and image

```
const ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText01;
var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

var toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Hello World!"));

var toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzdIt.jpg");

var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Comment: I am trying to send out the toast notification from one device out to a plethora of devices. This answer  will only send the notification to the device the app is running on.

Comment: I'm sorry, the question was not clear about `toast notification` and `push notification`.

Answer (score -3):

> Toast notifications are small pop ups that appear on the screen for few seconds. They convey messages and can be customized to even play different sounds.

See the [Windows Universal Apps notifications sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications) for more.